# Is it possible in MongoEngine to identify which object/document a GenericReferenceField refers to?

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am wondering if this is at all possible. Say I want to look through all my documents in a collection but want to filter out those who have a certain object set as GenericReferenceField()

Answer (score 1):

Looking for an object 'type' is a matter of how Mongoengine is serializing documents. So you could always use a **raw** query to inspect. Consider the following:

```
> use project1
switched to db project1
> db.page.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52e862b11d41c80802167cc4"),
    "title" : "Using MongoEngine",
    "bookmark_object" : {
            "_cls" : "Link",
            "_ref" : DBRef("link", ObjectId("52e862b11d41c80802167cc3"))
    },
    "date_modified" : ISODate("2014-01-29T13:08:49.315Z")
}
```

The class is just in the field _cls

```
from mongoengine import *
import datetime

connect('project1')

class Page(Document):
  title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)
  bookmark_object = GenericReferenceField()
  date_modified = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

class Link(Document):
    url = StringField()

#link = Link(url='http://mongodb.com/')
#link.save()

#page = Page(title='Using MongoEngine', bookmark_object=link)
#page.save()

pages = Page.objects(__raw__={ 'bookmark_object._cls': 'Link' })

for item in pages:
    print item.bookmark_object
```

Comment: So in other words bookmark_object.cls would contain the name of the Document? So you could in theory do 'item.bookmark_object.cls' and that would output Link ?

Comment: Actually 'item.bookmark_object._cls', but yes. It depends on your purpose on whether you just want to get at the class name or whether you want to query the collection for items that are matching that class. Similar cases work with objects in lists.